# C language exercise

Tags: c, for-loop, if-statement, char, do-while

Here is my other question.
I don't understand those pieces of code.
The output of the provided code is:

```
N
O
R
c
u
y
z
```

My questions are:

1. `a[i] > a[i + 1]`
   They're characters, not numbers. Why should we compare two characters?
   It doesn't make sense. or should I expect they yield boolean value?
2. `printf ("%c\n", a[i] + 2);`--> `a[i] + 2`
   It seems like something is happening with orders of array elements one by one. How and why?
   I understand the output should be 7lines of single characters.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main (void)
{
  char a[] = { 'w', 's', 'x', 'a', 'P', 'L', 'M' };
  int i, tmp, flag;
  do
    {
      flag = 0;
      for (i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    {
      if (a[i] > a[i + 1])
        {
          tmp = a[i];
          a[i] = a[i + 1];
          a[i + 1] = tmp;
          flag = 1;
        }
    }
    }
  while (flag == 1);
  for (i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    printf ("%c\n", a[i] + 2);
  printf ("\n");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: The code reads off the end of the `a` buffer when `i` is 6 in the first loop.

Comment: @Turuudo where have you found this bad code? 
do not drag any garbage here

Comment: Rather than figuring out this code, you would be better reading an introduction to C programming.

Comment: *"Why should we compare two characters? It doesn't make sense"* - Why not? Have you never looked for a word in a dictionary or a name in a phonebook?

Comment: Could you describe it in detail, please?

Comment: @Turuudo, characters are encoded in 8 bit values, e.g. `A` is 65, `B` is 66 (for ASCII), and so on, they can be compared as if they were `int`, actually in C they are `int`.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow This is my past exam material that I couldn't understand.

Comment: @Turuudo At first the code tries to sort the character array using the bubble sort method and then output its elements  with the offset 2 relative to given characters.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica. Sometimes, I refer directly to people rather than books or dictionaries.

Comment: @Turuudo, you're welcome, also note that `a[i] = a[i + 1];` will go out of the bounds of the array.

Comment: @Turuudo By the way are you from India?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow no, you're from Russia

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, when you store characters, it is stores their [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/) values for each character. So essentially, when you compare a[i] and a[i+1], it just compares the ASCII values for the characters (which is a numeric value less than 128). Same thing happens when you do a[i] + 2. It just adds 2 to the ASCII value and prints that character with that ASCII value. Since you program seems to sort the array of characters, the first character will be 'L' (capital L). It adds the +2 to this and hence this becomes 'N'.

Answer (score 1):

1. Characters are represented by ASCII codes, so they are numbers. Check out the ASCII table.
2. `a[i] + 2` does not affect the order. It affect the character. Again, look at ASCII table.

Answer (score 1):

Each character has a numeric value.
You can read about it here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII
Or to see the table that links each character to its numeric value, you can use the following link: http://www.asciitable.com/.

have a great day!!!

Answer (score 0):

The `char` type is an integer type.  Characters have an associated numeric encoding, and that's what is being compared.  In ASCII, that encoding is

```
'A' == 65
'B' == 66
'C' == 67
```

etc.  So it makes sense to compare `char` values and do arithmetic on them.  Those values are mapped to glyphs for display, but internally they're just numeric values.